# Use unique_ptr<std::vector> in combination with c-style arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, unique-ptr, class-design

## Problem

I have an old code base that is processing images. The C++ style is old (before C++11), there are no smart pointers or anything like that. Only a lot of dynamic allocation and raw pointers.

There is always only one actual image that is processed. These images are kept and passed as c-style arrays:

```
class A {
    A(double* image);
}

class B {
    B(){ image = new double[10]; };
    double* image;
} 

class C {
    C();
    foo(double* image);
}
```

I need to add a new class that manages and reads in images. And I would like to set up a class like this, because I feel pretty uncomfortable with all this dynamic allocation and would like to use more modern C++.

```
class NewImage {
     NewImage();
     double* getImage() { return &image.get()->at(0); };
     readImage();
     ...
private:
     std::unique_ptr<vector<double>> image;
}
```

1. Is it recommended to have such a `getImage()` function for handing over the image to the old part? Or should I use something like `std::unique_ptr<double> image`?

   - If I would use `std::unique_ptr<double> image`, would I need a custom deleter because the unique_ptr manages an array, and not a pointer to double?
2. Or shouldn't I use modern C++ at all and stick to the old style? With `double* image` and dynamic allocation?

Comment: One seldom, if ever, need a pointer to a vector. Sometimes one could need a vector of pointers, but this doesn't seem to be such a case. All you need is a plain vector.

Comment: You don't need pointers in the C++ implementation of this code.  To save overhead have the functions take the vector by reference.  If you need to give the vector to another object, then you can use move semantics to move it so you don't have the cost of  copy.

Comment: To expand on @Someprogrammerdude's comment : it's incredibly hard to justify a `std::unique_ptr<std::vector>` because there are essentially no added benefits to using it over a `std::vector>` (except maybe that it's nullable). But the use cases for a `std::shared_ptr<std::vector>` are a bit more common.

Comment: @NathanOliver What do you mean by "C++ implementation of this code"? A, B and C can't be changed, this would mean ra re-write of the whole application. I need an interface between NewImage and the old functionality, that only accepts double*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I wanted to use unique_ptr<vector> to demonstrate that NewImage is the owner of this image data and manages it for the whole application. Others mustn't be possible to set this to another image. I wanted to prohibit that someone from somewhere adds a setter and overwrites the actual image.

Comment: Unless you plan to to actually add a getter-type function for the vector, no one else will be able to access the vector directly. Not even if they inherit from your class. *But* if you don't want anyone to modify the stored data, then your `getImage` needs to be modified, because right now one could use it to get a pointer to the first element of the vector and then use it to modify any element in the vector (and even go out of bounds and invoke UB). You can't prevent the out-of-bounds indexing, but at least return a `const double*` (and make the whole function `const`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it recommended to have such a getImage() function for handing over the image to the old part?

If you have use for such function, then sure. A more modern alternative could be to return a `span` that encapsulates pointer to the beginning as well as the length of the array.

> Or shouldn't I use modern C++ at all and stick to the old style? With double* image and dynamic allocation?

Dynamic allocation is still used with the newer design. It's just hidden inside `std::vector`.

Note that `std::vector` has been in the C++ standard since the beginning, and managing dynamic array without a container is very old style pre-dating standard C++ (that's over two decades old now) and the STL before that. I don't know good arguments for staying with the old style.

---

P.S. There's probably no advantage for using the additional indirection of `std::unique_ptr`. It is probably more optimal to store the vector as a member directly.